# Performance particle system

Tags: javascript, three.js

I have 30,000 vertices, trying to animate them but at this point the performance drops have a suggestion on how to improve the code?

```js
function createParticle() {
  let tween;
  _.times(30000, n => {
    let vertex = shirt.geometry.vertices[n];
    let particle = particles.vertices[n];
    particle.x = 15 * 20;
    particle.y = 16 * 20;
    particle.z = 14 * 20;

    tween = new TWEEN.Tween(particle)
      .to({
        x: vertex.x * shirt.scale.x,
        y: vertex.y * shirt.scale.y,
        z: vertex.z * shirt.scale.z
      }, 3000)
      .onUpdate(function() {
        particleSystem.geometry.verticesNeedUpdate = true;
      })
      .easing(TWEEN.Easing.Sinusoidal.InOut)
      .start();
  });
}
```

Comment: `BufferGeometry` with `ShaderMaterial` will solve the problem of performance. I have an example of over 250 thousand points with 57-60 fps. Using thousands of tweens is not so good idea.

Comment: @prisoner849  thanks